# Alignment issue with layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have basic layout for a login screen on my app. I want to align the logo at the top of the screen. The email & password fields, & login button in the middle of the screen. Than the two buttons create account & forgot password at the bottom of the screen (stacked on top of each other). 
I can't figure out for the life of me how to do it. I tried to use "aligninParent" attribute which did work, but when I changed the phone orientation it caused the fields to overlap. Would I need to create a different layout for landscape?

My Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Login Form -->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@drawable/radialback">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- Logo -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/se_logo"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/se_logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
         <!-- Email Address -->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text">

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

       <!-- Password -->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/pw"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_edit_text" />

        <!-- Login Button -->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_style"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

          <!-- Link to Register -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnlink_to_register"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/create_account"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

             <!-- Forgot Password Button -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnlink_forgot_password"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use fill_parent, replace for match_parent (the former is deprecated).

Short answer: yes, you need different layouts for landscape if you want it to look differently.

You seem to be using tooooo many layouts.

The Logo shouldn't be inside a linear layout, you can use AlignParentTop=true for that image view.

The next LinearLayout (for email/user, etc.) should be "alignBelow=

Add IDs to your views/widgets if you use Relative Layouts, because that's how you position them in the screen.

Only use LinearLayouts to put individual groups of views together in a single block that can adapt as a whole.

Read a little bit about layout weight to have one of your views use the remaining "unused" space accordingly.

ANd post a screenshot of what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/login_iv"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/yourlogo" />

<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/rl_login"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/login_iv"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
   android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:hint="email" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPass"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:password="true"
        android:hint="password"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLogin"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPass"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```